# Firestore function deployment error when using Twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, twilio

I'm trying to integrate Twilio into a triggered Firestore function. The problem I'm having is when I add this code, I am unable to deploy ANY functions. As far as I know this is how to use twilio inside a cloud function. At the top I have this and I think firebase doesn't like something here because ALL functions stop deploying with this code.

```
// Used to send text messages
const twilio = require('twilio')
// const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid
// const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token

/* eslint new-cap: ["error", { "newIsCap": false }] */
const client = new twilio('ACblahblahblah', 'ccblahblahblah') // sid and token
const twilioNumber = '+13344714571' // your twilio phone number
```

Within the triggered function I have this. But I don't think the issue is here:

```
       return client.messages.create({
          to: someNumber,
          from: twilioNumber,
          body: 'Some message.'
        }).then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
```

I have a valid Twilio account set up. The function logs don't tell me much other than that the function cannot be initialized. What am I missing? Seems like this has worked for others.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you mean by "ALL functions stop deploying with this code".  What are you observing?  Be specific, and show any error messages.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using what you provide in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out about 5 minutes after posting the question. I had not installed twilio in the functions folder but rather the root of the project. Once I executed

```
npm install twilio
```

in the functions folder, the functions started deploying. Too bad there was no error in the logs that said something like "required package is missing" or something like that.